Mocha chai test cases are not completing due to on sinon stub
Am using a typical node express typescript project, where i have controller and service file, am trying to write simple testcase for controller file, its executes the test case but after that it's not finishing up, i meant its kinda struck i need to do ctrl+c, am attaching my code
import { expect } from "chai";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { getRewards } from "../src/controllers/rewardController";
import sinon from "sinon";
import * as rewardService from "../src/services/rewardService";

describe("Reward Controller", () => {
  let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  let req: Partial<Request>;
  let res: Partial<Response> & {
    status: sinon.SinonStub;
    json: sinon.SinonStub;
  };
  let next: sinon.SinonSpy;
  let getFilteredRewardsStub: sinon.SinonStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      query: {
        page: "1",
        pageSize: "10",
        club_id: "2",
        tenant_id: "16",
        membership_id: "1",
      },
    };
    res = {
      status: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      json: sinon.stub(),
    };

    console.log({rewardService});

    next = sandbox.spy();
    sandbox.stub(rewardService, "getFilteredRewards").resolves({
      rewards: [{ id: 1, name: "Reward 1" }],
      totalRecords: 1,
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
    console.log("complete")
  });

  it.only("should return rewards and pagination metadata", (done) => {
    // return Promise.reject();
    done()
  });

now it shows 1 passing but after that its not completing its struck in the same place, but if i remove
sandbox.stub(rewardService, "getFilteredRewards").resolves({
  rewards: [{ id: 1, name: "Reward 1" }],
  totalRecords: 1,
});

if i comment the above stub, its resolving(completing) am not sure what's the mistake am doing,
attaching the screenshot of the terminal

